# Random sampling from a set of integers

Tags: python, list, if-statement, random

I am working with python 3.2 and I spent a lot of time trouble shooting this, and I still can't seem to wrap my brain around it.

`number = random.randint ( x0 ,xn )`

I'm generating a random number. It's purpose is to make my code come at me differently everytime.

For example I have 10 variables of text that I have written. I have solved the problem of not having these variables appear in the same order at each program run.

The issue I have is that they now appear randomly everytime. It picks one out of 10 everytime, instead the first time 10 and next 9. I can't seem to find out how to exclude the previous ones.

```
thelist = [0]

while i < x
     if number in thelist:
         >>>repeat<<<
     else:
         thelist.append (number)
         if ( number == x0 ):
             >>>something<<<
         elif ( number == x1 ):
             >>>something<<<
```

This is what I would imagine the code would look like, everytime you loop one more number gets appended to the list, so that everytime it picks a number already in the list it repeats the loop again until it then has used all the numbers that random.randint can pull.

Comment: you may be looking for random.sample() ?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a shuffle function:

```
import random

max = 15
x = list(range(max+1))

for i in range(max, 0, -1):
    n = random.randint(0, i)
    x[n], x[i] = x[i], x[n]
```

This starts with a sorted list of numbers `[0, 1, ... max]`.

Then, it chooses a number from index 0 to index max, and swaps it with index max.

Then, it chooses a number from index 0 to index max-1, and swaps it with index max-1.

And so on, for max-2, max-3, ... 1

As yosukesabai rightly notes, this has the same effect as calling `random.sample(range(max+1), max+1)`. This picks `max + 1` unique random values from `range(max+1)`. In other words, it just shuffles the order around. Docs: http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample

If you wanted something more along the lines of your proposed algorithm, you could do:

```
import random

max = 15
x = range(max+1)
l = []

for _ in range(max+1):
    n = random.randint(0,max)
    while n in l:
        n = random.randint(0,max)
    l.append(n)
```

Comment: i think `x[n], x[i] = x[i], x[n]` is better than using `temp` to swap

Comment: @ragsagar true, I'll change my code. I often forget about the tuple-unpacking feature of python.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand of your description and sample code, you want `thelist` to end up with every integer between `x0` and `xn` in a random order. If so, you can achieve that very simply with `random.shuffle()`, which shuffles a list in place:

```
import random

x0 = 5
xn = 15

full_range = list(range(x0, xn))
print(full_range)
random.shuffle(full_range)
print(full_range)
```